# Calculate module of "Just int" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, option-type

I'm trying to calculate the module of an index of a list.

```
list=[5,6,7,8]
a = elemIndex 7 list
b = mod a 2
```

Ideally, this would give me `b = 0` since `a = 2` (technically).
But I'm getting error messages since `a` is not `2` but `Just 2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [**`fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) or its operator variant [**`(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-60--36--62-) to apply a function to the item wrapped in the `Just …` data constructor:

```
b = (`mod` 2) <$> a
```

this will then return `Just 0` when `a` is `Just 2`, and `Nothing` if the `elemIndex` returned a `Nothing`. This thus means that if `elemIndex` fails (because the index is out of range), `b` will be `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks Willem, this worked but now I'm facing another issue. The thing is that I actually need  a simple int. Is there a way to remove the "Just" when it's not "Nothing"?

Comment: @walter: the problem is: what will you do in case there is `Nothing`? `Maybe`s are usually used for computations that can "fail", and thus by using such a datatype, the programmer still knows they have to implement a case for `Nothing`.

Comment: That's the thing, I'm using implementing a code fairly more complicated than the example I posted. In my code, I'm sure the answer to the statement "a = elemIndex 7 list" can't be Nothing. I'm just using it to know the index of an element I already know belongs in the list.

Comment: I'm actually doing a kind of "for each element, give me the index and do the module"

Comment: @walter I encourage you to seek a solution that does not use `elemIndex`. For example, `zip (cycle [0,1]) xs` will give you a version of `xs` that has each element paired up with its index mod 2. The best way to turn a `Maybe X` into an `X` is to never have a `Maybe X` in the first place.

Comment: @walter: then you should not perform indexing on a list. A list is implemented in Haskell as a *linked list*, and will thus take *O(k)* time to get the *k*-th element

Comment: @DanielWagner I took the liberty to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use pattern matching with `let` to get to the inner part of the `Maybe` value when it is guaranteed to be `Just _`:

```
list = [5,6,7,8]
a = elemIndex 7 list
b = mod a 2

foo list = [b | n <- [5,6,7,8]
              , let a = elemIndex n [5,6,7,8]
              , let Just i = a
              , let b = mod i 2]
         = [b | n <- list
              , let Just i = elemIndex n list
              , let b = mod i 2]
         = [b | (_, i) <- zip list [0..]
              , let b = mod a 2]
         = ls where ls = [0,1] ++ ls

bar list = [(n,b) | n <- list
                  , let Just i = elemIndex n list
                  , let b = mod i 2]
         = [(n,b) | (n, i) <- zip list [0..]
                  , let b = mod i 2]
         = zip list ls where ls = cycle [0,1]
```

Normally this kind of pattern matching is frowned upon since it is *partial*, i.e. can cause error if the value is actually `Nothing`, but here it is correct by construction.

But then really, why put it into a `Just` -- just use it as it is. And we did.